# How can I transform data from (.ddm .pnt .fdt .bin) files to .csv

Tags: database, adabas

I have data stored in `.ddm`, `.pnt`, `.fdt` and `.bin` files.

How can I export (or extract or transform) data from those file formats into `.csv`?

I think it's an ADABAS database.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. 
The file extensions looks like an adabas database. 
You need an adabas/natural enviroment for running database and you can write a simple program in Natural for read database content and put them to  text "work file" with delimiters ";" and csv extensions. 
J don't met any tool for manual unpack database files.

Answer (score 0):

As peterozgood pointed out, you would normally use Natural for that.

If you're using Natural on Windows or Unix you can code the following

```
DEFINE WORK FILE nn  TYPE 'CSV'
```

...where nn is a number between 1 & 32, identifying the desired workfile.
(this may also be specified by your Admin in the so-called Natparm, along with Codepage & Delimiter)

Then you can output data to the file by coding

```
WRITE WORK FILE nn  operand1 ... operandN
```

Natural will automatically create the csv.
Fields will be separated by the delimiter and quoted and escaped as necessary.
(the delimiter may be specified in the Natparm or as a startup parameter)

Unfortunately this functionality is not available with Mainframe Natural.
(CSV that is. Workfiles are of course available)